# Python, Pandas, XML - split a XML element based on length

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I'm parsing an XML file, and one of the child elements occasionally contains more than 4000 characters.  When it does, I want to create a second element to store the overflow characters in, before saving it to a pandas dataframe.  Once I build the dataframe, I export it to Excel (I know how to do that).

Or when parsing and it has more than 4000 characters, dynamically create a new dataframe column to store the data in (I think this is the better solution as the data is exported to Excel for reporting)

```
import pandas as pd 
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getvalueofnode(node):
    if node is None:        
        return None     
    else:       
        soup = BeautifulSoup(node.text) # clean js keywords         
        text = soup.get_text()
        text = text.replace("\n", " ") # remove newline         
        text = text.replace("\r", " ") # remove newline         
        text = text.replace(' +', ' ') # remove duplicate spaces        
        return text

parsedXML = et.parse(filename) 
dfcols = ['datarec','casekey','description','narative'] 
df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

for node in parsedXML.getroot():        
    datarec = node.find('DATA_RECORD')
    casekey = node.find('CASE_KEY')         
    description = node.find('DESCRIPTION')      
    narative = node.find('CASE_NARRATIVE')      

    df_xml = df_xml.append(pd.Series([datarec, getvalueofnode(casekey), getvalueofnode(description), getvalueofnode(narative)], index=dfcols), ignore_index=True)
```

1. Headings are not that important, so I was thinking I don't need to define my df column names.  So I dynamically create a new column if the count exceeds 4000 (what happens at 8000, 12000?)
2. I'm thinking the way to do it, is by fixing the XML BEFORE building the dataframe, if I do that, how do I split it at 4000 characters and create a new element?
   2.1  If I do create a new element, I'm not sure my getvalueofnode function will return all the rows?

Which way shall I go?

Edit------ Copy of XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE main [
  <!ELEMENT main (DATA_RECORD*)>
  <!ELEMENT DATA_RECORD (CASE_KEY,DESCRIPTION?,CASE_NARRATIVE?)+>
  <!ELEMENT CASE_KEY (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT DESCRIPTION (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT CASE_NARRATIVE (#PCDATA)>
]>
<main>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <CASE_KEY>6479351</CASE_KEY>
    <DESCRIPTION>Four bill payments</DESCRIPTION>
    <CASE_NARRATIVE>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque accumsan congue risus, tristique imperdiet sapien consectetur nec. Donec ut urna lectus. Duis eget magna et quam aliquet porta non vitae enim. Proin diam ex, ullamcorper in lectus ac, cursus sollicitudin ipsum. Sed lorem urna, congue et condimentum in, rhoncus id nunc. Duis vel mauris pharetra, accumsan neque non, pellentesque leo. Nullam vel nibh vulputate, eleifend turpis condimentum, faucibus mi. Sed mattis dolor non libero scelerisque, in congue ligula ullamcorper. In finibus laoreet erat et venenatis. Aenean tincidunt magna a nisl euismod posuere tristique eget orci. Vestibulum ac turpis vel justo laoreet fermentum rutrum eget est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean blandit at leo vel pharetra. Duis vel commodo orci. 

        Praesent tincidunt mattis suscipit. Nam aliquet purus eu nibh ultrices, ac tristique risus euismod. Sed bibendum tincidunt elit, a finibus arcu bibendum at. Praesent turpis neque, auctor at dui ut, cursus rhoncus tortor. Cras rutrum, lacus et molestie posuere, odio purus porta nisi, vel egestas nulla nibh accumsan erat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer imperdiet, ligula ac iaculis iaculis, augue massa dapibus neque, sit amet iaculis orci nibh quis libero. Phasellus tortor ligula, luctus non mi quis, consequat dapibus risus. Vestibulum nec finibus ex. Duis ipsum nisl, tincidunt in erat rhoncus, pulvinar consequat tortor. Curabitur faucibus interdum metus. Morbi egestas ipsum ac rutrum faucibus. Maecenas non leo sem. 

        In ultrices, libero ut sagittis blandit, ex dolor pretium nibh, ac bibendum ligula nunc sed quam. In ultricies, arcu aliquam porta pharetra, orci mauris imperdiet lectus, a facilisis purus purus at sem. Nullam ac feugiat nulla. Duis congue lorem sit amet tellus varius ultrices. Curabitur risus mauris, rutrum ut sodales tempor, varius eget lectus. In eget hendrerit ligula, ac mollis mi. Nulla volutpat felis ornare elit facilisis dapibus. Fusce facilisis nisi est, eget gravida lorem aliquam nec. Ut sed purus sit amet mi sodales vestibulum id sit amet purus. Ut in vestibulum purus. Donec eget enim ipsum. Mauris eget neque neque. Pellentesque feugiat faucibus felis, quis tincidunt nisl. 

        In viverra posuere nulla sed cursus. Praesent nec rutrum enim, et gravida lorem. Fusce gravida lorem quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi at aliquam lacus. Nulla suscipit nibh eu congue finibus. Phasellus et sem non dolor tempus aliquam. Ut tincidunt elit erat, varius molestie lacus mattis feugiat. Ut lectus ex, suscipit non condimentum sit amet, condimentum vitae sem. Donec et scelerisque leo. 

        Suspendisse velit nisl, suscipit quis metus ac, suscipit sollicitudin libero. Nulla euismod lectus sit amet congue efficitur. Fusce a sagittis magna, ut fringilla mi. Ut suscipit lectus quis luctus euismod. Sed at dui fermentum, tincidunt risus sit amet, pretium diam. Etiam eleifend varius urna nec volutpat. Nam efficitur tellus non volutpat consequat. Mauris ut elit enim. Pellentesque sit amet tincidunt metus. Nam ornare massa quis libero fermentum sagittis. Sed facilisis turpis dolor, eget mattis lectus laoreet eu. 

        Aliquam egestas leo mauris, non placerat dolor euismod eu. Proin eget convallis augue. Suspendisse elit ante, ornare at augue sit amet, molestie elementum leo. Duis id leo in odio consequat auctor. Duis commodo elementum velit, porttitor blandit libero luctus commodo. Nulla in libero vel libero varius faucibus a non tellus. Pellentesque dapibus eget lectus id fringilla. Sed vitae nisi nisi. Sed ultricies orci vitae sapien ultrices, nec ornare tortor placerat. Vestibulum et ligula tristique, rhoncus dolor in, semper lorem. Integer non urna nec risus convallis pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vitae ullamcorper leo. Suspendisse potenti. 

        Sed congue, mi rutrum placerat bibendum, erat tortor finibus lorem, eget varius velit lacus ut mauris. Nullam congue placerat mollis. Duis et fringilla nunc, id dictum enim. Morbi non gravida nisi. In nec nunc ante. In vitae odio accumsan, imperdiet lectus a, egestas sapien. In sit amet elit pharetra, scelerisque turpis a, tincidunt nisl. Curabitur tempus eu risus et vulputate. Fusce iaculis diam quis nibh viverra, pulvinar fringilla massa fermentum. Proin elementum in felis sed rutrum. Etiam eget elit vitae turpis ultrices auctor lobortis a erat. Duis fermentum tristique consectetur. Fusce quis est tincidunt, ultricies erat a, pharetra est. 

        Nullam ac velit et ipsum cursus sodales. Pellentesque consequat quis dui ac aliquam. Suspendisse libero turpis, porttitor quis malesuada ut, interdum ac dui. Phasellus varius suscipit tristique. Praesent vel ante vel augue pellentesque tempus. Pellentesque volutpat finibus lorem, non malesuada nisi imperdiet eget. Proin dignissim mi non lorem imperdiet, sit amet mattis neque sodales. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus non nisl metus. 
    </CASE_NARRATIVE>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <CASE_KEY>6479356</CASE_KEY>
    <DESCRIPTION>Financial Crime Concern</CASE_NARRATIVE>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <CASE_KEY>6480409</CASE_KEY>
    <DESCRIPTION>Financial Crime Concern :M&#38;S customer was cold called by someone about an investment opportunity, the caller gave customer different options and she chose 3 to invest in. She was unaware of the scam until she was contacted by the police. There is a seperate scion case re the police notification</DESCRIPTION>
    <CASE_NARRATIVE>&#60;p&# Lorum Ipsum</CASE_NARRATIVE>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <CASE_KEY>6480519</CASE_KEY>
    <DESCRIPTION>Financial Crime </DESCRIPTION>
    <CASE_NARRATIVE>fraudster had set up two new payments and created </CASE_NARRATIVE>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <CASE_KEY>6480521</CASE_KEY>
    <DESCRIPTION>Triage Europe</DESCRIPTION>
    <CASE_NARRATIVE>Mr. Ockwell is a HB</CASE_NARRATIVE>
  </DATA_RECORD>
</main>
```

Comment: Please show XML for a reproducible example. Also [Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451)

Comment: Added the XML - will go read about quadratic copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `BeautifulSoup`, consider using `lxml` to run the siblings, XSLT and XPath:

- XSLT can transform your original XML for the added *OVERFLOW* element using the [`substring()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_substring.html) and [`string-length()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_string-length.html) functions.
- XPath can parse new, transformed tree for mapping values to a pandas data frame either with a loop or list/dict comprehension.

**XSLT** *(save as .xslt file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DATA_RECORD">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CASE_KEY|DESCRIPTION"/>
        <CASE_NARRATIVE>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(CASE_NARRATIVE), 1, 4000)"/>
        </CASE_NARRATIVE>
        <OVERFLOW>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(CASE_NARRATIVE), 4001, 
                                            string-length(normalize-space(CASE_NARRATIVE)))"/>
        </OVERFLOW>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(includes short list comprehension version and long loop version)*

```
import lxml.etree as et
import pandas as pd

# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
xml = 'Input.xml'
xsl = 'XSLT_Script.xsl'

# TRANSFORM SOURCE
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(xml)

# SHORT VERSION
data = [{el.tag: el.text for el in dr.xpath("*")} for dr in result.xpath("//DATA_RECORD")]

# LONG VERSION    
data = []
for dr in result.xpath("//DATA_RECORD"):
    inner = {}
    for el in dr.xpath("*"):
        inner[el.tag] = el.text 
    data.append(inner)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output**

```
print(df)
#   CASE_KEY                                     CASE_NARRATIVE                                        DESCRIPTION                                           OVERFLOW
# 0  6479351  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...                                 Four bill payments  s velit lacus ut mauris. Nullam congue placera...
# 1  6479356                                               None                            Financial Crime Concern                                               None
# 2  6480409                                     <p Lorum Ipsum  Financial Crime Concern :M&S customer was cold...                                               None
# 3  6480519  fraudster had set up two new payments and created                                   Financial Crime                                                None
# 4  6480521                                Mr. Ockwell is a HB                                      Triage Europe                                               None
```